# Trying to format my values in pandas Dataframe which r showing like 1,008.59-, 1008.59 (one space is there aftr +ve value) to -1008.59 and 1008.59

Tags: python, pandas

Amtindoccurre

1008.59 (right space is there after this value)
1008.59-

Need to format those values in proper format like 1008.59(without any right side space)and -1008.59 in Pandas Data frame.
Can any one tell the way how to do.

Thanks
DS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with regex to parse the float numbers with trailing sign and space and put the sign and space at the front.  Then use [`.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) to remove any space remaining:

```
data = {'val': ['1008.59 ', '1008.59-', '57,039.54 ', '4,232.49 ', '4,191.59-', '1,257,039.54 ', '2,257,039.54-']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['val'] = df['val'].str.replace(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)(\s|-)', r'\2\1', regex=True).str.strip()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

             val
0        1008.59
1       -1008.59
2      57,039.54
3       4,232.49
4      -4,191.59
5   1,257,039.54
6  -2,257,039.54
```

**If you want to remove the thousand separators `,` also**, you can use:

```
df['val'].str.replace(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)(\s|-)', r'\2\1', regex=True).str.strip().str.replace(',', '', regex=True)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

           val
0      1008.59
1     -1008.59
2     57039.54
3      4232.49
4     -4191.59
5   1257039.54
6  -2257039.54
```

**If you want to further convert the numbers from string to numeric values (float type)**, you can use:

```
df['val'] = df['val'].str.replace(r'(\d+(?:,\d+)*(?:\.\d+)?)(\s|-)', r'\2\1', regex=True).str.strip().str.replace(',', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Comment: Bu Applying the code df['val'] = df['val'].str.replace(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\s|-)', r'\2\1', regex=True).str.strip() some data is showing correct where as some data's are showing like       57, 039.54(a space between , and 0) and 4, 232.49(a space between comma and 2), and 4,-191.59 instead of -4,191.59.

Comment: @durgasankarNayak  I overlooked that there can be thousand separators.  Fine-tuned the codes to handle thousand separators as well.  Please retry.

Comment: @Seabean...Now its working fine A big thanks to u. and also can you tell me how to convert the same data to numeric as its all showing as string data type.

Comment: @durgasankarNayak  You can further use `.astype(float)`.  See my edit above.

Comment: @durgasankarNayak  Let me know whether the numeric conversion is fine with the code.

Comment: @Seabean...Yes the code is absolutely working for Numeric conversion. Thanks for the help